# What is the purpose of a t-distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, sampling, t-distribution

As far as I know, we use a t-distribution if the sample size is small and the population is normally distributed. But if the population is normally distributed, then the sample mean is also normally distributed, so why not just use the z-distribution instead?

Comment: dividing the sample mean by a random std. dev., however, does not produce a normal random variable.

Comment: Because we do not know the variance neither and need to estimate it from data. If you know the variance, of course, z.

Comment: It can also be used when estimating the difference of two means when the variances are unknown and assumed equal.

Comment: I am sure this question has a duplicate or duplicates on this site.

Comment: @Taylor Why is the variance a random variable? Don't we estimate it from the sample?

Comment: @Saad the sample variance is random. The population variance is true, usually unknown, and non-random in your case. The sample variance only estimates the true population variance. They are two very different things.

Comment: @Taylor So then if we have a small sample size with a known population variance, we can use z? And if we have a large sample with an unknown population variance, why can't we use t?

Comment: @Saad yes to the first one if you're assuming the data are normal. Regarding the second, you will most likely be using a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. When $n$ is large, this distribution is "very close" to a normal distribution. Sometimes teachers will tell you to memorize the rule that tells you to use a normal when the data is big. This is misleading in my opinion and obscures the main distinction between these two distributions.

Comment: @Taylor The problem with the z distribution was that the std.dev was random, so why does a large sample size nullify this? You're saying the t-distribution is a better choice in this case, but why does the z distribution work at all?

Comment: With a normal dataset, $Y_n = \sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)/s$ follows a $t_{n-1}$. This is true for any $n$. The sequence of random variables $Y_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal distribution as $n \to \infty$. It just gets closer and closer. These are two separate facts. You can prove this, but you should ask about this on a separate thread, or do a little digging.

Comment: @Taylor Thank you. So Y follows t(n-1) only if s is unknown?

Comment: $s$ is known (it's a sample sd). It's $\sigma$ (population sd) that we don't know.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the population standard deviation.

Comment: Could someone write a summary for all the cases i.e known s.d, small sample, unknown s.d, large sample etc